# How to give Column Name to ResultSet dynamically in this case?

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList as shown below

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Mann {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ArrayList<String> billOrderList = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("VAT");
        list.add("Discount");
        list.add("SERVICE CHARGE");

        StringBuilder select_query = new StringBuilder();
        select_query.append("Select ");

        for (int i = 0; i < billOrderList.size(); i++) {

            if (i != billOrderList.size() - 1) {
                select_query.append("" + billOrderList.get(i) + " , ");
            } else {
                select_query.append("" + billOrderList.get(i) + "");
            }
        }

        select_query.append(" From VENDOR_ITEMS WHERE vendor_items_id = "
                + vendor_item + "");

        VendorItems_Pstmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(select_query
                .toString());
        VendorItems_RSet = VendorItems_Pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (VendorItems_RSet.next()) {

            String tax_name = VendorItems_RSet.getString();
        }
    }

}
```

How can i give the column name which is dynamic in this case in line VendorItems_RSet.getString();??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need as [ResultSetMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) to get the column name associated with your query result.
You can get `ResultSetMetaData` from `ResultSet` by using [ResultSet.getMetaDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData()), you can iterate it and get column all column name.

```
ResultSetMetaData  VendorItems_RSet_metaData = VendorItems_RSet.getMetaData(); 
int numberOfColumns = VendorItems_RSet_metaData .getColumnCount(); 
for(int i=1;i<=numberOfColumns;i++)
{   
   String columnName = VendorItems_RSet_metaData.getColumnName(i);
}
```

I think you need all column data for that you can iterate your loop like

```
while (VendorItems_RSet.next()) 
{
  for(int i=1;i<=numberOfColumns;i++)
  {   
     String columnName = VendorItems_RSet_metaData.getColumnName(i);
     String tax_name = VendorItems_RSet.getString(columnName);
     System.out.println(tax_name); 
  }         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = VendorItems_RSet.getMetaData();
        for (int i = 1; i <= resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {            
            String type = resultSetMetaData.getColumnTypeName(i);  // Get Column type 
            String name= resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i);   //Column name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT *` and then

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = VendorItems_RSet.getMetaData();
int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 1; i <= columns; ++i) {
    System.out.println(metaData.getColumnName(1));
}
```